# „Du und deine Geschichten haben/habt ...“

Tags: conjugation

Since the interlocutor is listed in the subjects, I thought it would be 
second person. But somehow I intuitively think

> „Du und deine Geschichten haben mir ...“

would be the correct conjugation, instead of

> „Du und deine Geschichten habt mir ...“

Which (if any) is correct? If the first is correct, what is the reason behind this being so, notwhitstanding the fact that we say, for instance,

> „Du und deine Schwester habt mir ein Geschenk gegeben“

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb:

- Is it possible to replace the subject with *ihr*? -> 2nd person
  plural
- Is it possible to replace the subject with *wir*? -> 1st person
  plural

or more complicated:

[Duden - Das Wörterbuch der sprachlichen Zweifelsfälle (Chapter 2.1)](https://books.google.de/books?id=1-HBDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA570&lpg=PA570&dq=Bei%20der%20Verbindung%20von%20Subjektteilen%20in%20der%202.%20und%203.%20Person%20(du%20%2B%20er)%20ist%20das%20Gesamtsubjekt%20austauschbar%20mit&source=bl&ots=ruAZqcjtE5&sig=ACfU3U3U9qaZqO85ZX8GQKKD9pfdCmJZ_A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR8c7WhsjnAhX5zMQBHSwHC64Q6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Bei%20der%20Verbindung%20von%20Subjektteilen%20in%20der%202.%20und%203.%20Person%20(du%20%2B%20er)%20ist%20das%20Gesamtsubjekt%20austauschbar%20mit&f=false) says:

> Bei der Verbindung von Subjektteilen in der 2. (du/ihr) und 3. Person (er/sie) ist das Gesamtsubjekt austauschbar mit ihr; Verb und Pronomen werden entsprechend in die 2. Person Plural gesetzt.

[canoonet](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemPers.html)

> Sind eine 2. Person und eine 3. Person mit und verbunden, richtet sich das Verb nach der 2. Person Plural. Die beiden Subjekte können durch ihr zusammengefasst werden.

So as you can replace *Du und deine Geschichten* with *ihr* it's

> „Du und deine Geschichten habt mir ...“

Comment: Danke. Vielleicht hätte ich es mit einer Duckduckgo-Suche finden sollen, aber ich wusste nicht wie man auf den Suchbegriff kommt.

Comment: Es besteht die Möglichkeit, daß bei dieser Regel nur an Fälle gedacht wurde, bei denen beide Bestandteile Personen sind. Daß aus *du und Hans* ein *ihr* wird, ist plausibel: Man redet beide an, unabhängig davon, ob Hans anwesend ist. Aber *du und deine Geschichten* ist vielleicht anders, weil man die Geschichten nicht anreden will.

Comment: @DavidVogt Möglich, aber ich glaube das nicht. Man könnte auch sagen "Du und deine Geschichten ... ihr habt mir einen Riesenschrecken verursacht". Dasselbe Problem hätte man bei "Du und deine Freunde habt/haben".  Anders ist es bei einer oder-Verknüpfung. Da bezieht sich das Verb idR auf den ihm nächsten Teil (siehe canoo-Link in der Antwort)